# Html Agility pack ASP.NET C# Selecting Nodes 2 levels only Prints 1st value in foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

hey i am working on a web crawler in ASP.NET and using HTML Agility Pack for HTML Parsing .
Whenever I loop Foreach in a table and Want to SELECT and get value of Iteration Node It only Gives me first value repeatedly.

Here is my CODE

```
 public void Olxrun(String query)
    {
        string url = "http://olx.com.pk/all-results/?q=" + query + "&page=1"  ;
        var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
        var document = webGet.Load(url);

        try
        {
            var lnks = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'offer onclick  ')]");

            foreach (HtmlNode node in lnks)
            {
                Label1.Text += "
" + node.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@class,'price x-large margintop10')]").InnerText;

            }
        } catch(Exception exa)
        {
            Label1.Text += "Error";
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.//*[contains(@class,'price x-large margintop10')]`

`//`  will always start from the root element.

`.//` will start from the current node.